# sum numbers from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a mysql database with a variable that holds numbers. I would like to get these numbers on each row and put them in an array.  Then I would like to sum the numbers.  So far I can get the numbers from the array, but I cant add them.

CODE:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE book='$id'");
$max = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $max[] = $row['max'];
}
```

I now have numbers in the array, eg. `$max[8]=45`, but how can I add all the array numbers? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding values in an array.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330823/adding-values-in-an-array) and [How can i add all of my array values together in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439129/how-can-i-add-all-of-my-array-values-together-in-php) and [probably others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+array+sum+values).

Comment: sanitize your SQL ... remember bobby tables...

Comment: @Felix should this question be hammered or closed as Unclear?

Answer (score 3):

If you need only the sum from your database it is wise to use in SQL Instead of manipulating again in PHP code.
you can use
select sum (colname) from tablename

Optionally you can group or specify the criteria for the selection. It would be faster and always preferable until unless we explicitly needs some manipulation which cannot be done through the SQL.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that summing in the database may be faster - if you do this right, you will save the time needed for passing all the values from DB to PHP, because you will pass only one row.

Comment: True, but "If you need only the sum from your database" is important. I actually asked a question about this a little while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351478/getting-all-data-in-one-query-and-processing-in-php-vs-querying-repetitively-for/6351509#6351509

Answer (score 1):

Assuming max is field in your table. You can do something like:

```
SELECT sum(max) from table where book id =  $id
```

That way you wont need an additional step to calculate it.